# What is the syntax to return a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

I have the following (incomplete) method definition

```
public static U Test<T, U>(string param1, T someType) where T: SomeType where U : ?
```

What is the correct syntax to allow U to return any type (e.g. string, int).
i.e. what should be in place of the question mark

Comment: Just leave it without constraint?

Comment: If you don't need U to be constrained then you don't need to add a type constraint. Your method should be able to compile - if it doesn't, then the issue is with the method body (e.g. do you have a `return null;` where `return default(U);` would be more suitable, etc).

Comment: @Awakening Byte: Presumably the OP wants the return value to be strongly typed, hence the U param.

Comment: @BoltClock in this case,  I agree with your comment

Comment: The code doesn't compile when I leave out the where U : ? part. I tried to return a string but no compilation

Comment: You can't return a `string` because you claim to support returning an arbitrary type chosen by the caller. What should happen if `U = int`? If you want to return any type you chose, then return `object` and remove the `U` parameter.

Comment: generics purpose is to return User defined type which is provided on compile type

Comment: You can do this trick: `return (U)(object)myStringVariable;`

Answer (score -1):

If U will be a class type and you need the Test method to return an instance which it instantiates itself then you need to specify `where U : new()`. This can be combined with a type constraint in the where clause, e.g. `where U : ReturnType, new()` or `where U : IReturnType, new()`.

What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: the return type can be int or string

Comment: Then you probably should make the method return type dynamic instead if that's what you really need to do. I'm guessing you are going to use param1 to specify a property name and then use reflection to get the property value from the someType parameter, or something similar.

Comment: Or object, rather.